Different size on the menu bar options
I recently installed QGIS 3.36, coming from QGIS 3.26. But I'm not comfortable because the menu bar has different sizes between those versions.
I tried changing the size of the icons in the settings thinking it would fix my problem but no, considering both versions have the same settings I don't know what the problem is.
The steps I followed are: Settings > options > general > icon size > there I choose 24 in both versions, and it is still different.


